# how does the method infer the type of <T>

Tags: java, generics, gson

The below method works flawlessly

```
public <T> void fromJsonArray(String jsonString,Type tToken) {
  Gson g = new Gson();
  T list = g.fromJson(jsonString,tToken);
  System.out.println(list);
}
```

But i have not specified what < T > is in this method. how does the compiler assign the value returned by the `fromJson` method to the variable `list` whose type i have not specified?

i just tested the validity of the answers stating about `<T>` being inferred from the return type of the method. It doesn't seem to work out. Please check out the following code. it doesn't even compile

```
import java.util.*;

class Sample {

  public List<String> getT(String s) {
    List<String>  list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add(s);
    return list;
  }

  public <T> void test(){
    T list = getT("test");
    System.out.println(l);
  }

  public static void main(String[] a) {
    new Sample().test();
  }
}
```

modified the source again and tested it, and it resulted in a compile time error

```
public <T> List<T> getT(T s) {
  List<T>  list = new ArrayList<T>();
  list.add(s);
  return list;
}

public <T> void test(){
  T list = getT("test"); //incompatible types compilation error here
  System.out.println(list);
}
```

`Sample1.java:13: error: incompatible types
    T list = getT("test");
                 ^
  required: T
  found:    List
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Object declared in method test()`

Comment: Maybe it inlines the variable, as it's useless here

Comment: A type variable can be any non-primitive type you specify: any class type, any interface type, any array type.

Comment: This is a pretty good question. I don't see how it can be inferred from the arguments. `Type` is a non-generic interface with no methods at this time. I wonder if the compiler is able to infer based on the return type. The JLS for type inference is pretty difficult to understand. I don't personally know the answer.

Comment: @BlackPanther. Ok, how are you invoking that method? `fromJsonArray`?

Comment: @RohitJain Since it's void I am wondering if they are invoking it with no type argument (then Object is ultimately inferred for the complete call ...).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> **how does the method infer the type of `<T>`**

It doesn't. Generic methods don't infer their generic types - that's why `T` is called a *type parameter*. The *caller* of the method provides a type argument for `T`. When it does, it *may* be inferred by the compiler based on the context of the method call's arguments and target type.

For example:

```
Set<String> c = Collections.emptySet();
```

`emptySet` declares a type parameter `T`, takes no arguments, and returns a `Set<T>`. Here, the compiler infers `T` to be `String` based on the target type, `Set<String>`.

Another example:

```
Collections.singleton("asdf");
```

`singleton` declares a type parameter `T`, takes a `T`, and returns a `Set<T>`. Here, there is no target type, but the compiler infers `T` to be `String` based on the argument `"asdf"`.

But generic type inference is just a convenience. Without it, we could still use *type witnesses* to explicitly provide type arguments:

```
Set<String> c = Collections.<String>emptySet();
Collections.<String>singleton("asdf");
```

This brings us to your method signature:

```
public <T> void fromJsonArray(String jsonString, Type tToken)
```

`fromJsonArray` declares a type parameter `T`, but doesn't return anything related to the type `T` or take arguments related to `T`. At a call to `fromJsonArray`, the compiler has no information from which to infer `T`. Its type argument will default to its upper bound `Object` unless a type witness is used:

```
myObj.<String>fromJsonArray(jsonString, tToken);
```

But this doesn't matter because `<String>` has no affect on the behavior of the method call or its compilation. `T` is meaningless[*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20410837/different-return-value-types-in-implementation-of-generic-methods) and can be removed from the declaration of `fromJsonArray`.

> **how does the compiler assign the value returned by the `fromJson` method to the variable `list` whose type i have not specified?**

Here is the source of [`Gson.fromJson(String, Type)`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases/org.jbpm.jbpm3/gwt-console/1.0.0.Beta2/com/google/gson/Gson.java#Gson.fromJson%28java.lang.String%2Cjava.lang.reflect.Type%29):

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public <T> T fromJson(String json, Type typeOfT) throws JsonParseException {
    StringReader reader = new StringReader(json);
    T target = (T) fromJson(reader, typeOfT);
    return target;
}
```

You can see it declares an arbitrary type parameter `T` and casts the deserialized object to `T`. This is known as an *unchecked cast*, because it won't fail fast if it's wrong. That's because `T` has been [erased](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) at runtime. You can see that the code is suppressing a warning about doing this, because it's generally a bad idea. By not restricting what `T` is based on the method arguments, the Gson code has effectively ceded control over it to the caller. If you wrote:

```
List<String> list = g.fromJson(jsonString, tToken);
```

but `tToken` represented `HashSet<String>`, you would get a `ClassCastException` on that line at runtime. Worse, if `tToken` represented `ArrayList<Integer>`, it would not even fail on that line, because the JVM would only see a `List` and allow the assignment to happen. A `ClassCastException` would be thrown sometime later, once your code tried to treat the list's `Integer` elements like `String`s (and the exception would be confusing to debug).

So to answer your question about the assignment, the compiler lets you assign the result of `fromJson` to anything you want. It's up to you for it to be correct.

You may ask, **Why would Gson do an unchecked cast and allow unsafe code?** The answer is that it's a convenience, stemming from language limitations. Their other signature is safer:

```
public <T> T fromJson(String json, Class<T> classOfT)
```

But there's no way to represent generic types with `Class` - no `List<String>.class` for example. Only a `Type` can do this, and it's not itself generic. `fromJson` could have required a `TypeToken<T>`, but there are other ways to obtain a `Type`, so that would be restrictive.

Returning `Object` and forcing the caller to do the unchecked cast would have been more transparent but the Gson developers probably wanted to avoid this "ugliness".

Comment: Following the code further, I see that that the typeOfT is converted to Class. The code is in TypeUtils class.

Comment: @Ritesh Would you mind linking to that? I don't see it.

Comment: [TypeUtils.toRawClass](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases/org.jbpm.jbpm3/gwt-console/1.0.0.Beta2/com/google/gson/TypeUtils.java#TypeUtils.toRawClass%28java.lang.reflect.Type%29)

Comment: @Ritesh Sorry I'm just trying to understand what you mean by "Following the code further" - what's the call hierarchy linking `toRawClass` back to `fromJson`?

Comment: I just browsed (or clicked) through the source code at the link you added and found the reference. I am not familiar with the Gson but overall it seems (from the javadocs and from classes such as TypeToken, JsonDeserializationContext, JsonDeserializationVisitor, ParameterizedTypeHandlerMap, and ParameterizedTypeImpl) that a great deal of code is there to provide the feature for any parameterized type (in addition to the simple case of Class<T>) and it is not a type inference. New Type adapters can be registered to customize serialization (see javadoc of com.google.gson.JsonSerializer).

Comment: In short, what you wrote in your answer is absolutely correct.

Comment: @PaulBellora : hi.. thanks for the answer.. i tried out what you said using some sample code and it resulted in compile time incompatible types error.. can you take a look at my edit..? :)

Comment: @BlackPanther `getT` is different from `fromJson` in that it takes a `T` and returns a `List<T>`. There is no way to guarantee that the `T` declared by `test` is a `List`. Besides that, passing `"test"` in as an argument of type `T` implies that `T` is `String`. A closer example to what Gson is doing would be `public <T> T getT(String s) { ... }`.

Comment: i tried this and it worked.. `public <T> T getT(String s) {
    T thing = (T)s;
  return thing;
}` guess i have to dive deep into generics and learn of its intricacies..

Comment: @BlackPanther As long as it's clear that such a method isn't safe, since `T` isn't guaranteed to be `String`. It's just a nonsensical example to demonstrate compiler behavior. Gson's unchecked cast makes more sense since the cast object has been created using reflection and there's no alternative for generically typing it.

Comment: I completely understood what you were referring.. :) i would like to know more on this topic.. maybe i should go through the JLS on type parameters a little more..

Answer (score 3):

```
T list = g.fromJson(jsonString,tToken);
```

It's inferred from the return type of `g.fromJson().`

Comment: i have tried it but its not the case i guess... please look at my edit.. thanks for the response..:)

Comment: The return type of g.fromJson is inferred from the method argument 'tToken' (Type)

Comment: @Ritesh: i understand that the return type of the method `fromJson` is inferred from the type parameter, what i would like to know is how that inference helps in inferring the type of `T` in my method

Comment: Not sure I got it. By definition, a generic method uses type parameters to express dependencies among the types of one or more arguments and/or its return type. If you see signature of fromJson, you will find that it is using type parameter to indicate that its argument (typeOfT) is deciding the return type T. Your method fromJsonArray is also a generic method- its second argument is typeOfT and its signature is indicating that return type is of same type.

Comment: To be more clear, you can change the signature of fromjsonArray as: <T> fromJsonArray(String, Class<T>)

Comment: Of course it's the case. Just because you couldn't get your own incorrect example to compile proves nothing. The fromJson() method *does* compile.

Comment: i understand that the `fromJson` compiles and so does the one i have given in the question. But what bugs me is that the codes i have given in my edit doesn't compile. can you please point out what i have done wrong in it.. Sorry if i sound dumb or naive... this concept of type inference is really causing an itch in my brain.. i really would like to get this understood..

Comment: i understood a little from @paul's answer.. i guess i have to learn a lot more of the intricacies of generics.. thanks for your answer... :)