# Java - Generic Factory Class

Tags: java, oop, generics, factory

I have an HTTP client class that uses Generics. I would like to create a factory class that has a map with (key, value) => (String type, HttpClient<?>).

The `HttpClient` class has one function that just sends data to the server depending on the generic class type. Essentially what I want to have is a generic class that sends data, that's it.

The issue is that I have multiple classes and I wanted to use a factory class in order to:

1. Simplify the creation of HttpClient's objects.
2. Avoid using the "new" keyword all the time because I can use the same instance of the `HttpClient<Some Object>` class throughout my application.

Please see code below:

Factory

```
public class SystemPreferencesFactory {

    private static SystemPreferencesFactory factory = null;
    private  Map<String, PreferencesHTTPClient<? extends ISystemPreferences>> preferencesMap;

    private SystemPreferencesFactory(){
        this.preferencesMap = Map.of
                (PreferencesHTTPType.DUT_PREFERENCES.getName(), new PreferencesHTTPClient<DutPreferencesDTO>(PreferencesHTTPType.DUT_PREFERENCES.getUrl()),
                PreferencesHTTPType.MACHINE_PROPERTIES.getName(), new PreferencesHTTPClient<MachineProperties>(PreferencesHTTPType.MACHINE_PROPERTIES.getUrl())
                );
    }

    public static PreferencesHTTPClient<? extends ISystemPreferences> getPreferencesHTTPClient(String type) {
        if (factory == null) {
            factory = new SystemPreferencesFactory();
        }
        return factory.preferencesMap.get(type);
    }

}
```

HttpClient

```
public class PreferencesHTTPClient<T> extends HTTPClient {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerManager.getLogger();
    private static String route = "";

    public PreferencesHTTPClient(String route){
        this.route = route;
    }

    public Future<HttpResponse> put(T dto) {
        try {
            System.err.println(dto.getClass());
            HttpPut request = new HttpPut(URIAffix + route + "/" + SystemPreferences.systemPreferences().getSetupName());
            request.addHeader("Authorization", authorizationPassword);
            request.addHeader("Content-Type","application/json");
            request.setEntity(new StringEntity(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(dto)));

            return getClient().execute(request,
                    new FutureCallback<>() {
                        @Override
                        public void completed(final HttpResponse response) {
                            logger.info("update request succeeded");
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void failed(Exception ex) {
                            logger.error("update request failed: {}", ex.getMessage());
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void cancelled() {
                            logger.error("update request canceled");
                        }
                    });
        } catch (JsonProcessingException | UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            logger.error("update request failed: {}", e.getMessage());
        }

        return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(null);
    }
}
```

When I try to call it in main I get an compile error

```
SystemPreferencesFactory.getPreferencesHTTPClient(PreferencesHTTPType.DUT_PREFERENCES.getName())
                 .put(converterUtil.DutFromEntityToDTO(dp));
```

The compile error is:

```
Required type:
capture of ? extends ISystemPreferences
Provided:
DutPreferencesDTO
```

My DutPreferencesDTO class is declared as so:

```
public class DutPreferencesDTO implements ISystemPreferences
```

What is wrong with my syntax?

Comment: You cannot call `put` at it accepts a wildcard method argument. As soon at `T` is bound to `?` you cannot use the method any more - this is the classic Java generics covariance example. The idea is that the type of your client is `?` (a specific unknown type) and therefore the compiler cannot determine whether what you’re trying to pass in is of the correct type - classic example being a `List<? extends Number>` - you cannot `add` as the compiler cannot know whether you’re adding the right type. To solve you need to declare your `put` method as bounded on `? extends T`.

Comment: Thanks for the response. However, I am not sure I followed you suggestion, can you give me an example of how to declare my put function?

Comment: `public <E extends T> Future<HttpResponse> put(E dto)`. I’m not certain that will work with all your other wildcards - I haven’t got an IDE in front of me and you haven’t really posted a MCVE

Comment: I added it and now gets error: Inferred type 'E' for type parameter 'E' is not within its bound; should extend 'capture<? extends com.altair.infrastructures.dataobjects.systemPreferences.ISystemPreferences>' Also, where is the use of E, it is only declared but I never used it

Comment: Also I want the put method to return a Future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can modify `getPreferencesHTTPClient` as below:

```java
public class SystemPreferencesFactory {

...
                  // Change to generic method
    public static <T extends ISystemPreferences> PreferencesHTTPClient<T> getPreferencesHTTPClient(String type) {
        if (factory == null) {
            factory = new SystemPreferencesFactory();
        }
        // cast result explicitly
        return (PreferencesHTTPClient<T>) factory.preferencesMap.get(type);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SystemPreferencesFactory.getPreferencesHTTPClient(PreferencesHTTPType.DUT_PREFERENCES.name())
                .put(new DutPreferencesDTO());
        // Oops wrong dto still compiles
        SystemPreferencesFactory.getPreferencesHTTPClient(PreferencesHTTPType.DUT_PREFERENCES.name())
                .put(new MachineProperties());
        // Assign to a local variable to infer
        PreferencesHTTPClient<DutPreferencesDTO> preferencesHTTPClient = SystemPreferencesFactory.getPreferencesHTTPClient(PreferencesHTTPType.DUT_PREFERENCES.name());
        preferencesHTTPClient.put(new DutPreferencesDTO());
        // Compile error;
        preferencesHTTPClient.put(new MachineProperties());
        // Use type witness to guard
        SystemPreferencesFactory
                .<DutPreferencesDTO>getPreferencesHTTPClient(PreferencesHTTPType.DUT_PREFERENCES.name())
                // Compile error;
                .put(new MachineProperties());
    }
}
```

### Seems not bad.
But as demonstrated in the main method, there is one drawback.

We need to **explicitly infer** the type when we call `getPreferencesHTTPClient`, to get desired type checking. But Others using this method may easily forget to do so and may put wrong type of DTO when calling `put` method.

So to avoid such problem, we use the **Class of DTO**, instead of `String` in `getPreferencesHTTPClient` as follows:

```java
public class SystemPreferencesFactorySafe {
    private static SystemPreferencesFactorySafe factory = null;
    private Map<Class<?>, PreferencesHTTPClient<? extends ISystemPreferences>> preferencesMap;

    private SystemPreferencesFactorySafe() {
        this.preferencesMap = Map.of
                (DutPreferencesDTO.class, new PreferencesHTTPClient<DutPreferencesDTO>(PreferencesHTTPType.DUT_PREFERENCES.getUrl()),
                MachineProperties.class, new PreferencesHTTPClient<MachineProperties>(PreferencesHTTPType.MACHINE_PROPERTIES.getUrl())
                );
    }
                  // T is inferred by type this time
    public static <T extends ISystemPreferences> PreferencesHTTPClient<T> getPreferencesHTTPClient(Class<T> type) {
        if (factory == null) {
            factory = new SystemPreferencesFactorySafe();
        }
        return (PreferencesHTTPClient<T>) factory.preferencesMap.get(type);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SystemPreferencesFactorySafe.getPreferencesHTTPClient(DutPreferencesDTO.class)
                .put(new DutPreferencesDTO());
        // Good we see compile error.
        SystemPreferencesFactorySafe.getPreferencesHTTPClient(DutPreferencesDTO.class)
                .put(new MachineProperties());
    }
}
```

Since the type is inferred using the parameter, we don't need explicit infer to get compile error when someone put wrong type of DTO.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I'm checking it out. I am not sure I understand the syntax of the function declaration: "public static <T extends ISystemPreferences> PreferencesHTTPClient<T> func()" can you please explain it? What the function returns?

Comment: What the method return depends on how you infer `T`. Check [how does the method infer the type of <T>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22280055/how-does-the-method-infer-the-type-of-t) for details.